# Using pickle file to set class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to implement a load and save method for a custom class via pickle.
(We may use no parameter to instantiate the class and later use 'load' to fill a and b respectively in this example)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a = None, b = None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def save(self, fname):
        # this works well
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f)

    def load(self, fname):
        # This does not work
        with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
            self = pickle.load(f)
```

The above code does not work, could anyone give me some suggestions? I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  We can't help you if you can't tell us precisely how it doesn't work.  Does it have a syntax error?  Does it just not load?  Does it set your computer on fire?  Please see [ask] for information on asking a question well.

Comment: could you leverage `cls.__dict__` and use `self.__dict__.update(**params)`?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein "does not work' mean nothing happen. The code would run but nothing get changed within the object (I mean a and b in this case).

Comment: works for me in python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Your `load()` should return a new object, for example:

```
def load(self, fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

and the call, something like this:

```
x = x.load(fn)
```

where `x` is the object name.

Alternatively (see comments) you could just pickup the attributes:

```
def load(self, fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        tmp = pickle.load(f)   
    self.a = tmp.a
    self.b = tmp.b
```

However you might be better off just saving the attributes to the pickle rather than the object.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way that I could change the variables within the existing object in this scenario?

Comment: Yes.  I'll mod. the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got the answer (from your answer and C.Nivs 's answer)